# My website is being attacked by IP range 66.249.72

Tags: wordpress, ddos

I am being attacked by IP ranges as shown below.
[image: 66.249.66.82 66.249.66.36 66.249.66.27 66.249.66.143 66.249.66.135 66.249.66.75 66.249.66.59]
I did a search on Google and found that it is an IP address range owned by Google LLC and located in United States https://developers.google.com/search/apis/ipranges/googlebot.json

it makes my site quite slow. I'm also curious if that's the exact reason.
So should I block it with Cloudflare?

[image: Last 30 minutes]

As of September 16th, my website is dropping about 30% of traffic compared to the previous time. even though it was just yesterday showing signs of recovery. and requests from those IP addresses show no sign of decreasing.

[UPDATE] My website is dropping about 30% of traffic compared to the previous time. even though it was just yesterday showing signs of recovery. and requests from those IP addresses show no sign of decreasing
[image]

[image]

[Update Oct 3]

I found out that this is really a ddos attack (they are still attacking in greater numbers) through google bot. they copy my content to post on their website. then they attack with google bot so that google penalizes my articles
[image]

Comment: What user agent is the attack using?  What is the rate of requests?

Comment: I updated it in the question

Comment: I still don't see the user agent.  How many pages do you have on your site?

Comment: Too many, maybe 50k pages

Comment: Then I agree with davidgo's answer.  This is just Googlebot crawling your large number of pages.

Comment: but my traffic started to drop a lot

Comment: You usually need to treat Googlebot as a first class user unless you don't mind getting kicked out of search engines.  You may need to find better hosting.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you are being attacked.  The IP addresses in question have a reverse DNS of crawl-xx-xx-xx-xx.googlebot.com - This is Google trying to index your site.

What is likely happening is that it is indexing too much to fast and thus taking on the characteristics of a DoS attack.

Google has advice on https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en on how they would like you to handle this.   Blocking them is likely not the answer.

Comment: Confirmed. These are legitimate Google Bot IPs.

Comment: i have selected "calculated as optimal" but the problem still doesn't improve

Comment: The url I linked to heavily implies that can take a couple of days to go into effect.

Comment: my current situation is site speed is stable but traffic keeps dropping

Comment: they copied my content and carried out the attack as @davidgo said.

Comment: Since you are blocking GoogleBot, your traffic (from Google) will probably continue to drop. Go into your Search Console, and check your coverage, it is most probably trending downward every day.

Comment: I never blocked it. I just reduced the crawl settings

Answer (score 3):

How did you determine this IP address range is slowing down your site? Depending on the software used, there are options to implement **rate limiting** if Cloudflare isn't enough.

In the screenshots you posted there is nothing that suggests abnormal rates coming from that IP range.

Things you could do, assuming you're on a Linux server:
use the `top` command from the command line, that is SSH. Let it run for a while and figure out what's keeping the server busy. It could be something else, a database server for example.

Checks the web server **logs**. You could also try something like: `tail -F /var/log/httpd/access.log` (the path is approximate but should be something along these lines) to follow the requests being made to your web server in real time. Some pages could be CPU-intensive for whatever reason, think about a page running a complex SQL query that is unoptimized for example.

Speaking of the logs, it depends on which server software you use, but the logs may show the **time** consumed to process a request. So perhaps you should start scrubbing your logs. Bash commands like `cut`, `awk` or even Perl could come in handy to parse the logs and find anomalies.