# my website is working fine but the traffic keeps dropping and i can't find the reason

Tags: seo, wordpress, ddos

[image]

[image]

[My website is being attacked by IP range 66.249.72](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/140366/my-website-is-being-attacked-by-ip-range-66-249-72)

My website is experiencing a huge drop in traffic even though it's working properly. I found that the IP address of google bot accessing my website a lot. I am very stuck as to what is the reason. Please help me. Thank

Comment: Which kind of traffic is dropping? Direct? Referral? SEO? Just looking at how much Google bot is crawling your site only gives us a very limited picture. If you suspect SEO traffic is dropping, have you checked Google Search Console?

Comment: Questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are considered off-topic here, and there's really not enough details to know what the issue might be. As noted in the above comment, it's also unclear what you mean by "huge drop in traffic", since it appears from the screenshots that most things have _increased_: Page Views, Visits, and API Requests... Please edit this to clarify what kind of traffic dropped and how you're measuring that, and add specific details regarding any changes to your site or potential issues with your hosting.

Comment: As noted in the answer to your previous question, you can [decrease the Googlebot crawl rate](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/48620?hl=en), which would only affect resource consumption on your server but shouldn't effect SEO unless your server becomes unresponsive. As also noted in the comment above, the best place to look for issues regarding crawl errors and indexing issues is in Google Search Console.

Comment: In that image I mean the IP address of the google bot (the one in the image) that didn't visit my website before.

Comment: It looks like your site didn't get any traffic at all before a few weeks ago.  Is this a brand new site?  If so, you need ta have a year of experience before you can really start doing traffic trend analysis.  Traffic could be seasonal for example.

Comment: my website from 500k to 1 million hits per day